# Lots of weird stuff happening today

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, power

So I'll just list the symptoms I've experienced in the last few hours, so far I can't seem to find a pattern, suffice to say the macbook is virtually unusable for my purposes. It's a 2010 Macbook white:

- Can't open Chrome
- Refuses to remember wifi password each time I reconnect
- Mail.app thinks it's offline
- Time keeps resetting to 12:00am
- Turns off randomly

I'm leaning towards blaming the battery, given the power loss and time resetting, however shouldn't there be a watch battery keeping time? Also I don't think I could explain the other issues blaming the battery. I suppose it's possible multiple things broke all at once. Thought I'd ask however and see if this isn't a known issue.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: do a hard reboot. Try again while plugged into auxiliary power.

Comment: Does Apple Hardware Test report anything?  (See http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1509;  I am guessing for a 2010 MacBook you will need the disc that came with the computer.)

Comment: ended up taking it to the Genius Bar and they did the Network Boot Test thingy and said the battery was kaput. New battery has fixed all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was the battery. Got it tested for free at the Genius Bar, and they did the replacement for the cost of the battery.